# SQL merge startdate and endate

Tags: t-sql, date, merge

I want to merge several start dates and enddates from a log event (so 1 row for one date).

Input table is:

```
Ord    Desc2    Date_Time
--------------------------
0      Down     1/1/2014      ==> Not merged because no Up after
1      Down     1/2/2014      ==> Rows 1 and 2 should be merged
2      Up       1/3/2014      
5      Down     1/4/2014      ==> Rows 5 and 12 should be merged
12     Up       1/6/2014      
13     Up       1/7/2014      ==> Not merged because no Down before
```

So results I'm looking for would be:

```
Ord    DesactivationDateTime    ActivationDateTime
----------------------------------------------------
0      1/1/2014   
1      1/2/2014                 1/3/2014
5      1/4/2014                 1/6/2014
13                              1/7/2014
```

SQL Request I've found was this one but it only works for UP/Down couple:

```
SELECT EventsDesactivation.Ord
    , EventsDesactivation.Desc2
    , EventsDesactivation.Date_Time AS DesactivationDateTime
    , MIN(EventsActivation.Date_Time) AS ActivationDateTime
FROM Journal AS EventsDesactivation

LEFT OUTER JOIN Journal AS EventsActivation

ON EventsActivation.Module=EventsDesactivation.Module --This is one of common rows not displayed in this sample...

WHERE
    (EventsDesactivation.Desc2 = 'Down') 
    AND (EventsActivation.Desc2  = 'Up')
    AND (EventsActivation.Ord > EventsDesactivation.Ord)
GROUP BY EventsDesactivation.Ord, EventsDesactivation.Desc2, EventsDesactivation.Date_Time
```

I'd appreciate if you helped me to find the solution!
My last idea was to do a crazy UNION ALL on couples and singles rows with a final GROUP BY...

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
François

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches your sample data and expected results but I've got a nagging feeling I'm missing some edge case(s):

```
declare @t table (Ord int, Desc2 varchar(13),Date_Time date)
insert into @t(Ord,Desc2,Date_Time) values
(0     ,'Down','20140101'),
(1     ,'Down','20140102'),
(2     ,'Up','20140103'),    
(5     ,'Down','20140104'),
(12    ,'Up','20140106'),
(13    ,'Up','20140107')

;With numbered as (
    select Ord,Desc2,Date_Time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ord /* or date_time? */) as rn
    from
        @t
)
select
    CASE WHEN n1.Desc2='Up' and n2.Desc2='Up' THEN n2.Ord ELSE n1.Ord END,
    CASE WHEN n1.Desc2='Up' and n2.Desc2='Up' THEN NULL ELSE n1.Date_Time END,
    CASE WHEN n1.Desc2='Down' and n2.Desc2='Down' THEN NULL ELSE n2.Date_Time END
from
    numbered n1
full outer join
    numbered n2
        on
            n1.rn = n2.rn - 1
where
    not (n1.Desc2='Up' and n2.Desc2='Down')
```

Basically, we join each row with the row that logically comes after it. We ignore `Up` rows which are followed by `Down` rows. And then we just have to work out if it's `Down,Up` (normal), `Down,Down` (report the first row's values only) or `Up,Up` (report the second row's values only)

Result:

```
----------- ---------- ----------
0           2014-01-01 NULL
1           2014-01-02 2014-01-03
5           2014-01-04 2014-01-06
13          NULL       2014-01-07
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this answer! Would you've a solution to have only one SELECT with ROW_NUMBER() use? I'm not sure that my final SQL client will allow such like request... Whatever, sounds good! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've applied your idea to my real world  and it works perfectly in a stored procedure. Thanks for that!
BUT my SQL client doesn't support stored procedure... Shame on me!

So I decided to create a table function (with pamareters) to call this SQL code.

Unfortunately, I didn't find the way to use you intermediate numbered table (called Event in my use)...
I got following error on line ";WITH Events AS" :
==> select statements included whithin a function cannot return a data to a client.

Here is function code I've done:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSensorsDesactivations 
(
    @dateStartInString nvarchar(50) = '',
    @dateEndInString nvarchar(50) = '',
    @Unit nvarchar(50) = null,
    @HoursToAddFromGMT int = -2,
    @DesactivationEventsFilter nvarchar(50) = 'Validation et Désactivation%',
    @BeforeDesactivationComment nvarchar(50) = 'Validation et Désactivation Capteur par ',
    @AfterDesactivationComment nvarchar(50) = '. Commentaire : ',
    @ActivationEventsFilter nvarchar(50) = 'Activation Capteur par%',
    @BeforeActivationUsername nvarchar(50) = 'Activation Capteur par '
)
RETURNS @TableTempToReturn TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    --Ord int,
    Unit nvarchar(50),
    Module nvarchar(255),
    Module_Description nvarchar(255),
    DésactivationQui nvarchar(255),
    DésactivationDateTime nvarchar(255),
    DésactivationMessage nvarchar(255),
    ActivationQui nvarchar(255),
    ActivationDateTime nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ExcludeOrds AS nvarchar(255) -- Must be comma separated and also at first and last character
    DECLARE @dateStart AS datetime -- to cast datetime from string because Dream Report is not able to pass parameters with formulas
    DECLARE @dateEnd AS datetime -- to cast datetime from string because Dream Report is not able to pass parameters with formulas
    SET @ExcludeOrds=',,,,,,,,,'
IF @dateStartInString='' OR @dateEndInString=''
    BEGIN
        --Init dates from yesterday to today if they are null
        SET @dateEnd=GETDATE()
        SET @dateStart=DATEADD(year, -1, @DateEnd)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Convert datetime from string to datetime format + hours from GMT to follow local datetime settings
        SET @dateEnd=DATEADD(hour, @HoursToAddFromGMT, CONVERT(datetime, @dateEndInString,  121))
        SET @dateStart=DATEADD(hour, @HoursToAddFromGMT, CONVERT(datetime, @dateStartInString,  121))
    END
IF @Unit IS NULL SET @Unit='WIP-BC2'

--Calculate positions/orders of differents Activation and desactivation events
;WITH Events AS   -- Here is my SQL error: select statements included whithin a function cannot return a data to a client.

(
    SELECT Ord, Unit, Module, Module_Description, Desc2, Date_Time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Unit, Module, Ord) AS rn
    FROM
        EJournal.dbo.Journal
    WHERE
        Date_Time <= @dateEnd
        AND Unit = @Unit
        AND (Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter
                OR Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter)
        --AND (Date_Time like @ActivationEventsFilter and Date_Time<=@dateStart)
        AND CHARINDEX(CAST(Ord AS nvarchar), @ExcludeOrds,1)=0
)

--Depending on desactivation and activation orders, select good Events in Activation/descativation columns
SELECT
    --n1.Ord,n2.Ord, n1.Desc2, n2.Desc2,
    n1.Module
    , n1.Module_Description
    , CASE
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ''
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(LEFT(SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeDesactivationComment)+2, 255 )
                    , CHARINDEX(@AfterDesactivationComment, SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeDesactivationComment)+2, 255)) - 1), '')
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(LEFT(SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeDesactivationComment)+2, 255 ), '')
                    , CHARINDEX(@AfterDesactivationComment, SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeDesactivationComment)+2, 255)) - 1)
        ELSE ''
        END AS DésactivationQui
    , CASE
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ''
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar, n1.Date_Time,  121), '')
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar, n1.Date_Time,  121), '')
        ELSE ''
    END AS DésactivationDateTime
    , CASE
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ''
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, CHARINDEX(@AfterDesactivationComment, n1.Desc2)+LEN(@AfterDesactivationComment), 255 ) , '')
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND (n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter OR n2.Ord IS NULL)
            THEN ISNULL(SUBSTRING(n1.Desc2, CHARINDEX(@AfterDesactivationComment, n1.Desc2)+LEN(@AfterDesactivationComment), 255 ) , '')
        ELSE ''
    END AS DésactivationMessage
    , CASE
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ISNULL(SUBSTRING(n2.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeActivationUsername)+2, 255 ),'')
        WHEN (n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter OR n1.Ord IS NULL) AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ISNULL(SUBSTRING(n2.Desc2, LEN(@BeforeActivationUsername)+2, 255 ), '')
        --WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter THEN ''
        --  THEN ''
        ELSE ''
    END AS ActivationQui
    , CASE
        WHEN n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar, n2.Date_Time,  121),'')
        WHEN (n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter OR n1.Ord IS NULL) AND n2.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter
            THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar, n2.Date_Time,  121),'')
        --WHEN n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter
        --  THEN ''
        ELSE ''
    END AS ActivationDateTime

FROM
    Events n1
FULL OUTER JOIN
    Events n2
    ON      n1.rn = n2.rn - 1
            AND n1.Unit=n2.Unit
            AND n1.Module=n2.Module

WHERE NOT (n1.Desc2 like @ActivationEventsFilter AND n2.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter)
        AND n1.Desc2 like @DesactivationEventsFilter
        AND n1.Date_Time <= @dateEnd
        --AND n2.Date_Time <= @dateEnd
        AND (n2.Ord IS NULL OR n2.Date_Time>=@dateStart)

RETURN
```

END

Would you've a magic solution for it ?

Thanks again for your help!
François